# Managing state for onBackPressed in Flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

So I have a simple list that's clickable and goes to DetailScreen, issue I have is when I click back from the DetailScreen, how can I manage this state to save the last list?

Bloc

```dart
if (event is GetNews && !_hasReachedMax(state)) {
      try {
        if (currentState is NewsInitial) {
          final news = await fetchNews(event.cat, pageNumber);
          yield NewsLoaded(news, false);
        }
        if (currentState is NewsLoaded) {
          pageNumber++;
          final news = await fetchNews(event.cat, pageNumber);
          yield news.isEmpty
              ? currentState.copyWith(hasReachedMax: true)
              : NewsLoaded(currentState.node + news, false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
        yield NewsError("Error fetching news" + error);
      }
    } else if (event is GetDetailedNews) {
      try {
        final filter = await fetchDetailedNews(event.id);
        yield DetailedNewsLoaded(filter);
      } catch (error) {
        yield NewsError("Couldn't fetch news : $error");
      }
    }
```

Attaching the event to the bloc

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _postBloc = BlocProvider.of<NewsBloc>(context)
      ..add(GetNews(widget.cat));
  }
```

BlocBuilder

OnBackPressed I'm just stick in the `else` since I don't know how to manage the state

```dart
    return BlocBuilder<NewsBloc, NewsState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is NewsLoaded) {
          return ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: state.hasReachedMax
                  ? state.node.length
                  : state.node.length + 1,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                fullList = state.node;
                print("list: ${state.node} \nlength: ${state.node
                    .length} \nindex: $index \n--------------");
                return index >= state.node.length ?
                BottomLoader() :
                listViews(context, state.node[index], index);
              });
      }
      else if (state is NewsError) {
          return Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Text(state.message),
              ));
      }
      else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      }
    });
```

States

```dart
abstract class NewsState extends Equatable {
  const NewsState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class NewsInitial extends NewsState {
  const NewsInitial();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class NewsLoading extends NewsState {
  const NewsLoading();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
class NewsLoaded extends NewsState {
  final List<Node> node;
  final bool hasReachedMax;

  NewsLoaded(this.node, this.hasReachedMax);

  NewsLoaded copyWith({List<Node> node, bool hasReachedMax}) {
    return NewsLoaded(node ?? this.node, hasReachedMax ?? this.hasReachedMax);
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [node];
}

class DetailedNewsLoaded extends NewsState {
  final List<Node> node;

  DetailedNewsLoaded(this.node);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [node];
}
}
```

In the detail screen i add the GetDetailScreen event, and this event stays when onBackPressed

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    BlocProvider.of<NewsBloc>(context)
      ..add(GetDetailedNews(widget.id));
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate NewsBloc object? I can't see in the code. Make sure you're not doing it inside _build_ function.

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin I added the event in the initState like in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your state when you press to see the article changes  to `DetailedNewsLoaded`. So when you press back `BlocBuilder<NewsBloc, NewsState>` goes to the else state which returns the `CircularProgressIndicator`.

As i understand in your case you don't need the `DetailedNewsLoaded` state. You can just need to pass the state.node to `DetailsScreen` as a simple argument.

Comment: Those are two different API endpoints, I'm using the `DetailNewsLoaded` to load the news by the id, which returns a single article.

Comment: Ok ,i understand. So if you `print(state)`; inside `blocBuilder`, i believe, you will see the state is `DetailedNewsLoaded`. That's where the problem appears. Maybe you can think to create two different Blocs in you case. One `NewsBloc` for your list of news an another one `DetailsNewBloc` for every article. Then when you press the button to see the article you can use something like 

`BlocProvider(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => DetailsNewBloc()..add(LoadArticle(id)),
  child: DetailsScreen(),
);`

Comment: Maybe you have already check it but in any case, i think you can see again how the todos app uses states and events from the examples https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial?id=states I think it's very close to what you want to do. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Why to do so much when you already have the [hero widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be9UH1kXFDw) in Flutter.

1. Make a List.
2. Use Hero animation for both list items and their details view.
3. Whenever the list item is clicked the details view will be shown.
4. When user presses back button, he/she will come to the position where that particular list item was.

So, basically you don't have to much.

I was going through some projects and I found this on github: https://github.com/whatsupcoders/Flutter-Hero-Widget

This project is walked through in this video that I found on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgSB5r11_Xw&t=15s

this project uses Hero widget, I hope it helps you.

Comment: The goal is to learn & practice how to implement Bloc library for bigger projects. So the code is easier to upgrade/change in future.

Comment: Okay, then this may not help you it seems.